# Questions that SAGE, MAGMA can answer?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computer-algebra-systems, sagemath, magma-cas

I practice theoretical mathematics and I  know (almost) nothing about SAGE, MAGMA. I would like to know (in general) what type of questions can I ask SAGE to do? For example, I know that given an explicit number field, softwares like SAGE, MAGMA can compute its Galois group, discriminant and MANY other things. But is the converse possible? That is, if I give a finite (solvable) group $H$ (of course for which Galois inverse problem has been proved), is SAGE able to give me an explicit field $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $H$ as its Galois group over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I don't know anything about these either, but this recently released database may help in such questions: http://www.lmfdb.org/

Comment: I don't see the interest in SAGE doing that. Either it has been solved and then you can look at what the answer is in the appropriate article, or it hasn't been solved and SAGE won't be able to answer. In any case it wouldn't be a computation, but just fetching an answer in a databse.

Comment: @CaptainLama The same could be said of any SAGE function. You could equally say what's the point of having an online database when there are books with tables from the 1920s. The point is that now it's possible to search through hundreds of examples in a few minutes rather than a few days. As far as I know SAGE can't give examples of number fields with a particular Galois group (I tried to exactly this a few months ago, but it was a small enough example that I could work it out by hand).

Comment: @Mathmo123 The point of SAGE is not to be a database of examples, but to compute stuff. If it does not compute something but looks for it in a pre-entered list of known examples, then it's just a glorified memo. (Of course it doesn't mean that you shouldn't implement lists of examples in it, but it's just not the point of the software in my opinion.)

Comment: @CaptainLama suppose I want to find an example of a group with property X. If SAGE had a database of small finite groups (and it does), I could iterate through the database and find an example in minutes. If it didn't, I'd have to input each finite group manually (already an exercise which would take a few minutes). How is that not what SAGE should be?

Comment: You may wish to use also `computational-algebra` and/or `gap` tags (maybe instead of `computer-algebra-systems` and `algebraic-number-theory`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can get e.g. sage to run through all polynomials of a given degree and ask it to compute their Galois groups until you get a hit, but this has been done before. In such a case it is a much better idea to look into one of the many existing data bases, e.g. http://galoisdb.math.upb.de/ or http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~numberfieldtables/ .